# How to resolve the error on a survey on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, share, survey

I am getting 
Sorry, something went wrong
The list doesn't allow setting of content types when i enable information management policies under a survey on SharePoint 2013. I have searched from the net but no avail. Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As with each error in SharePoint: take the GUID and look it up through the SharePoint log files...